# MongoDB Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression error

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

My data is having following structure

```
public enum ParamType
{
    Integer=1,
    String=2,
    Boolean=3,
    Double=4
}

public class Gateway
{
    public int _id { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}

public class Device
{        
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter
{
    public string ParamName { get; set; }
    public ParamType ParamType { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I filled 10 document objects of Gateway in a MongoDB database. 
Now I want to query all those gateways which contains a device having Parameter with `ParamName` as "Target Temperature" and whose `Value` > 15.

I created following queries

```
var parameterQuery = Query.And(Query<Parameter>.EQ(p => p.ParamName, "Target Temperature"), Query<Parameter>.GT(p => int.Parse(p.Value), 15));

var deviceQuery = Query<Device>.ElemMatch(d => d.Parameters, builder => parameterQuery);

var finalQuery = Query<Gateway>.ElemMatch(g => g.Devices, builder => deviceQuery);
```

But when I run this, it is giving an exception

```
Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: (Parameter p) => Int32.Parse(p.Value)
```

Please suggest where I am wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error suggests, you can't use `Int32.Parse` inside your query. This lambda expression is used to get out the name of the property and it doesn't understand what `Int32.Parse` is.

If you are querying a string, you need to use a string value for comparison:

```
var parameterQuery = Query.And(Query<Parameter>.EQ(p => p.ParamName, "Target Temperature"), Query<Parameter>.GT(p => p.Value, "15"));
```

However, that's probably not what you want to do since you're using `GT`. To be treated as a number for this comparison you need the value to actually be an int in mongo, so you would need to change the type of your property:

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string ParamName { get; set; }
    public ParamType ParamType { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

var parameterQuery = Query.And(Query<Parameter>.EQ(p => p.ParamName, "Target Temperature"), Query<Parameter>.GT(p => p.Value, 15));
```

Comment: None of the alternatives you provided solved my Use Case. It is yielding no records.

Comment: @AmitKumarJain should it? what do you have in your DB, does a regular mongo query returns results?

Comment: I am having 10 gateway documents in my DB and each Gateway is having one device with one parameter named "Target Temperature" with value "20". When I modify my query as var parameterQuery = Query.And(Query<Parameter>.EQ(p => p.ParamName, "Target Temperature"), Query<Parameter>.EQ(p => p.Value, "20")), it is returning records. But when I execute the Query with GT with argument 15 it is not returning records. I am running query with var result = mGatewayCollection.Find(finalQuery);

Comment: @AmitKumarJain if all your documents have 20 as a value, filtering with 15 shouldn't return any results. Filtering with 20 should.

Comment: But I am filtering them with Query.GT. Whether this will also not make any sense?

Comment: @AmitKumarJain oh, of course it doesn't work. Value is a string, not a number. Strings don't have an order, at least not the order you think of. If you want to use < or > you need to change `Value`'s type to a string.

Comment: I got your point but if am not able to change the data type of Value, because it is not sure that all the values of all parameters of all devices are integer. We have different devices having different parameters having different types of values like, Boiler Status parameter having boolean value, System Name parameter having string value, Holiday Start parameter having DateTime value etc. That's why I have one more member ParamType indicating which type of parameter it is. So you mean to say what I want cannot be achieved using MongoDB until I changed the type of Value.

Comment: @AmitKumarJain you definitely can't do that using a simple query. You probably can using JS and map reduce. I think you should ask a new question specifically about that (put the link here and I'll take a look).

Answer (score 0):

#### Summary

I ran into this when I was modifying a list.  It appears that `Linq First/FirstOrDefault` was not handled well by MongoDB for me.  I changed to be an array index `var update = Builders<Movie>.Update.Set(movie => movie.Movies[0].MovieName, "Star Wars: A New Hope");`  Note: This is in Asp.Net 5 using MongoDB.Driver 2.2.0.

#### Full Example

```
public static void TypedUpdateExample() {
  var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
  var database = client.GetDatabase("test");

  var collection = database.GetCollection<Movie>("samples");

  //Create some sample data
  var movies = new Movie {
    Name = "TJ",
    Movies = new List<MovieData>
    {
      new MovieData {
        MovieName = "Star Wars: The force awakens"
      }
    }
  };

  collection.InsertOne(movies);

  //create a filter to retreive the sample data
  var filter = Builders<Movie>.Filter.Eq("_id", movies.Id);

  //var update = Builders<Movie>.Update.Set("name", "A Different Name");
  //TODO:LP:TSTUDE:Check for empty movies
  var update = Builders<Movie>.Update.Set(movie => movie.Movies[0].MovieName, "Star Wars: A New Hope");
  collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
}

public class Movie {
  [BsonId]
  public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public List<MovieData> Movies { get; set; }
}

public class MovieData {
  [BsonId]
  public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

  public string MovieName { get; set; }
}
```