# MongoDB Driver C# Strongly Typed Nested Index

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a way to create a strongly typed nested index using the C# Driver.

I want this sort of index: `db.foos.ensureIndex({'Bars.Baz': 1});`

```
public class Foo {
    public Something() { }

    public List<Bar> Bars { get;set; }
}

public class Bar {
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}

var collection = database.GetCollection<Foo>("foos");
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(Builder<Foo>.IndexKeys.Ascending(/*What goes here?*/));
```

---

The following works but creates an index of "Bars.0.Baz":

```
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(Builders<Foo>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.Bars[0].Baz));
```

This doesnt work at all and comes up with a serialization error

```
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(Builders<Foo>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.Bars.Select(y => y.Baz)));
```

This works but adds an index of "Baz"

```
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(Builders<Foo>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.Bars.First().Baz));
```

None of them want to add an index of "Bars.Baz"

MongoDB driver version is 2.4.3.23

Answer (score -1):

try something like:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Foo>("foos");
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(Builder<Foo>.IndexKeys.Ascending(f=> 
                                              f.Bars.Select(str=> str.Baz)));
```

Comment: `System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to determine the serialization information for x => x.Bars.Select(y => y.Baz).`

Comment: Thats strange...
I tried to run it as is:
var collection = _FilesDb.GetCollection<Foo>("foos");
                    collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<Foo>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.Bars.Select(y => y.Baz)));

and it created the key.

I checked youe error and find this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039274/mongodb-unable-to-determine-the-serialization-information-for-the-expression-err

I guess your REAL object has an isuue... try to check this out.

Comment: What version of mongodb driver are you using, mine doesn't seem to like the linq select statement

Comment: I am yet using the previous one – 2.1.0.
Do you have general problem with linq query, or only for this use case?

Comment: Just seems to be for this use case, I've opened a support ticket on their JIRA but no reply as of yet